# How to server index.html from a subdirectory

Tags: google-app-engine

**myapp.appspot.com**  serves index.html from my war folder. Check.

**myapp.appspot.com/subdir/**  serves index.html from my war/subdir folder. Check.

What I want to do is for
**myapp.appspot.com/subdir**  (Nb no trailing slash) to serve index.html from my war/subdir folder. Instead I get a

> Error: Not Found
>
> The requested URL /subdir was not found on this server.

In case it's significant, this is a Java project

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure you app.yaml like this:

```
- url: /subdir
  script: /subdir/index.html
```

Comment: It's a Java project, not Python